# Internal Speakers and Mic Not Detected

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

I just installed Ubuntu on my Dell All-In-One Inspiron 5477, after I gave up on solving this same problem on Arch Linux.

I can hear audio from my headphones when they are connected, and input audio through headset mic when they are connected, but when they are not, I cannot hear anything, nor can I input anything. In the sound settings, there are no output/input devices besides "Dummy Output", so I don't think they are detected.

`aplay-l` gives me:

```
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`alsamixer`:
https://i.ibb.co/G7tnFf4/Screenshot-from-2021-01-21-19-02-58.png

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still struggling with this:
I had a similar problem that persisted for a while, found a couple things which didn't work (including running "sudo apt purge timidity-daemon"?) but in the end I found this link: https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/ and managed to fix it just by running "sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio" (no need to reload alsa or reboot)

If this still doesn't fix it, you have my sympathy

Comment: Still struggling with this, thanks for the answer, but it did not work for me. I ended up just buying a cheap mic and just using headphones, although it would be nice to be able to use the speakers.